# Reducing the Number of Training Samples for collaborative filtering recommender systems in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I have the following problem: I am doing some research on the accuracy of recommender algorithms that are mostly used nowadays.

So, one way to measure their performance is by checking how well they predict a certain value under different sizes of a given dataset, meaning, sparsity in a ratings matrix.

I need to find a way to calculate the root mean square error(or mae), some metric, versus the sparsity in the dataset. As an example, let’s have a look at the picture below:

[image]

You can see that it says:

> “RMSE as a function of sparsity. 5000 ratings were removed from the training set(initially containing 80000 ratings) in every iteration. “

I’m using Python and the Movielens dataset. Do you know how can I achieve this in the mentioned language? Is there any tool to do that?

Small example using the Surprise package:

```
from surprise import SVD
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import accuracy
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load the movielens-100k dataset (download it if needed),
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')

# sample random trainset and testset
# test set is made of 25% of the ratings.
trainset, testset = train_test_split(data, test_size=.25)

# We'll use the famous SVD algorithm.
algo = SVD()

# Train the algorithm on the trainset, and predict ratings for the testset
algo.fit(trainset)
predictions = algo.test(testset)

# Then compute RMSE
accuracy.rmse(predictions)
```

[Source to Surprise](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html)